# Estructura de app dinamica con informacion extraída de db externa

Tags: android

Estoy realizando un proyecto y me gustaría que me recomendárais cuál es la forma más óptima de realizar el siguiente paso de mi actividad. La idea es una app en la que la actividad tiene 6 layouts diferentes, cada uno con un tipo de información, por ejemplo si fuera de recetas, un layout tendría los ingredientes, otro los utensilios y otro lo pasos a seguir. Cada vez que complete la información que sale en pantalla pulsar siguiente y que todas las ventanas refrescaran con los siguientes pasos extraídos de la db. La info de la db ya la tengo cargada en la app desde el comienzo, para evitar tiempos de carga.

He estado informándome un poco y al parecer no hay manera de crear actividades dinámicamente, por el tema del manifest. Entonces imagino que lo que tengo que hacer es un  layout base con fragments y vistas y a partir de ahí, replicarlo en java, puede ser??

El tema de que sea dinámicamente es para que si se añade información a la db, no haya que tocar la app.

Tengo la limitación de android 7.0 para la api, por el dispositivo al que va dirigido.

Dicho esto, ¿Cuál es vuestra recomendación ?

Un saludo y muchas gracias.

Comment: Entiendo que lo que es dinámico son los productos no las categorías.No veo el problema divides la pantalla en 6 por ejemplo y dependiendo si tiene productos o no el layout lo ocultas el tema de datos no te importa si es dinámico ya que serán datos en un listado imagino.

Comment: Digamos que sí, lo que es dinámico són los productos, pero estará dividido en "n" pasos. En cad apaso quiero mostrar los artículos correspondientes y cuando se complete dicho paso, que se pueda acceder al siguiente.

Comment: La complejidad de lo comentas es mas como lo montes en BBDD para gestionar el orden de los productos

Comment: Pues sigo viendo la parte más compleja la de la app, la DB la tengo acabada y realmente no sé si tengo que seguir probando con fragmentos con N instancias o si existe alguna otra manera, puedes recomendarme ?

Comment: Usaría los fragmentos para no repetir código pero como te dije la información dinámica viene de BBDD pero los objetos que usas para mostrarla no es necesario que sean dinámicos. Sobretodo si usas listView para mostrar la información.

Comment: Muchas gracias, seguiré probando a ver.